# Cxf SOAP logging. Different services in different files

Tags: logging, soap, cxf

My problem is I have to work with different services and:
1. Having this in my beans.xml

```
<cxf:bus >
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>

    </cxf:bus>
```

and this in log4.xml:

```
 <logger name="org.apache.cxf" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="sessionSoapFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

I can see im my console only soap from one of all my service clients. And I cant' understand why. Can add that service that write logs correctly declared like this:

```
<jaxws:client id="sessionService" address="${session-storage.url}/services/SessionService?wsdl" serviceClass="ru.vtsft.exchange.session.service.SessionService">
    <jaxws:dataBinding>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding" />
    </jaxws:dataBinding>
</jaxws:client>
```

And services that doesn't like this:

```
<bean id="agencyClient" class="comtech.swc.service.AgencyService"
        factory-bean="agencyFactory" factory-method="create" />

    <bean id="agencyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass" value="comtech.swc.service.AgencyService" />
        <property name="address" value="${swc.url}/agency" />
        <property name="outInterceptors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor" />
                <ref bean="authorizationOutInterceptor" />
                <bean class="ru.vtsft.exchange.cxfinterceptors.DynamicIdOutInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

As result I want to write soap logs from different services in different files.
Thanks in advice and sorry for my english=)

Answer (score 1):

Oookay, last night I got it!
cxf doesn't write logs for second type client because of I override his own interceptors. Solution is:

```
<bean id="exchangeFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass" value="comtech.swc.service.ExchangeService" />
        <property name="address" value="${swc.url}/exchange" />
        <property name="inInterceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" /> <!---- Here -->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="outInterceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" /> <!---- And here -->
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor" />
                <ref bean="authorizationOutInterceptor" />
                <bean class="ru.vtsft.exchange.cxfinterceptors.DynamicIdOutInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <!-- Logging interceptors -->
 <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
 <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
```

Thank for your attention=)